# How else can I optimize this C program for dgemm blocked matrix multiplication?

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-optimization, matrix-multiplication

I have this C program for matrix multiplication, I've read about and tried loop unrolling... But other than that I have no idea how to speed up the C program. Could someone point me in the right direction of what else I can do?

```
const char* dgemm_desc = "Simple blocked dgemm.";

#if !defined(BLOCK_SIZE)
#define BLOCK_SIZE 41
#endif

#define min(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))

/* This routine performs a dgemm operation
 *  C := C + A * B
 * where A, B, and C are lda-by-lda matrices stored in column-major format. 
 * On exit, A and B maintain their input values. */
void square_dgemm (int lda, double* A, double* B, double* C)
{
  /* For each block-row of A */
  for (int i = 0; i < lda; i += BLOCK_SIZE)
    /* For each block-column of B */
    for (int j = 0; j < lda; j += BLOCK_SIZE)
      /* Accumulate block dgemms into block of C */
      for (int k = 0; k < lda; k += BLOCK_SIZE)
      {
        /* Correct block dimensions if block "goes off edge of" the matrix */
        int M = min (BLOCK_SIZE, lda-i);
        int N = min (BLOCK_SIZE, lda-j);
        int K = min (BLOCK_SIZE, lda-k);

        /* Perform individual block dgemm */
if( (M % BLOCK_SIZE <= 2) && (N % BLOCK_SIZE <= 2) && (K % BLOCK_SIZE <= 1 ))
        {
            do_block_fast(lda, M, N, K, A + i + k*lda, B+ k + j *lda, C + i + j*lda);
        }else
        {
            do_block(lda, M, N, K, A + i + k*lda, B + k + j*lda, C + i + j*lda);

        }
      }
}
```

Main program, that calls the subroutines do_block_fast() and do_block().

```
void do_block_fast (int lda, int M, int N, int K, double* A, double* B, double* C)
{
 static double a[BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
 // make a local aligned copy of A's block
   for( int j = 0; j < K; j++ )
    for( int i = 0; i < M; i++ )
     a[i+j*BLOCK_SIZE] = A[i+j*lda];
   /* For each row i of A */
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    /* For each column j of B */
         for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
         {
           /* Compute C(i,j) */
             double cij = C[i+j*lda];
             //for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k){
              //  cij += a[i+k*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[k+j*lda];
            // }

             for (int k = 0; k < K; k+= 41)
             {
                cij += a[i+k*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[k+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+1)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+1)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+2)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+2)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+3)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+3)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+4)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+4)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+5)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+5)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+6)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+6)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+7)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+7)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+8)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+8)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+9)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+9)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+10)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+10)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+11)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+11)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+12)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+12)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+13)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+13)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+14)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+14)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+15)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+15)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+16)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+16)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+17)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+17)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+18)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+18)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+19)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+19)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+20)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+20)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+21)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+21)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+22)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+22)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+23)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+23)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+24)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+24)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+25)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+25)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+26)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+26)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+27)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+27)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+28)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+28)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+29)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+29)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+30)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+30)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+31)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+31)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+32)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+32)+j*lda];
                cij += a[i+(k+33)*BLOCK_SIZE] * B[(k+33)+j*lda];
                     ...
                     ...
               }
             C[i+j*lda] = cij;
          }
}
```

Subroutine do_block_fast()... Basically since I know the value of K = 41, I just unrolled the innermost for loop by 41.

```
static void do_block (int lda, int M, int N, int K, double* A, double* B, double* C)
{
  /* For each row i of A */
  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    /* For each column j of B */
    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
      /* Compute C(i,j) */
      double cij = C[i+j*lda];
      if(K % 8 == 0)
      for(int k = 0; k < K; k += 8){
        cij += A[i+k*lda] * B[k+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+1)*lda] * B[(k+1)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+2)*lda] * B[(k+2)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+3)*lda] * B[(k+3)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+4)*lda] * B[(k+4)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+5)*lda] * B[(k+5)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+6)*lda] * B[(k+6)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+7)*lda] * B[(k+7)+j*lda];
              }
      else if(K % 7 == 0)
      for(int k = 0; k < K; k += 7){
        cij += A[i+k*lda] * B[k+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+1)*lda] * B[(k+1)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+2)*lda] * B[(k+2)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+3)*lda] * B[(k+3)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+4)*lda] * B[(k+4)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+5)*lda] * B[(k+5)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+6)*lda] * B[(k+6)+j*lda];
              }
      else if(K % 6 == 0)
      for(int k = 0; k < K; k += 6){
        cij += A[i+k*lda] * B[k+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+1)*lda] * B[(k+1)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+2)*lda] * B[(k+2)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+3)*lda] * B[(k+3)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+4)*lda] * B[(k+4)+j*lda];
        cij += A[i+(k+5)*lda] * B[(k+5)+j*lda];
              }
      ...

      else
      for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k)
        cij += A[i+k*lda] * B[k+j*lda];
      C[i+j*lda] = cij;
    }
}
```

Subroutine do_block(). Since I don't know the value of K I just used branching statements, to unroll the innermost for loop.

Lastly here are the results of the program

```
Size: 31    Mflop/s:  2361.82   Percentage:  5.51
Size: 32    Mflop/s:   2941.3   Percentage:  6.86
Size: 96    Mflop/s:  2861.72   Percentage:  6.67
Size: 97    Mflop/s:  2657.44   Percentage:  6.19
Size: 127   Mflop/s:  3028.53   Percentage:  7.06
Size: 128   Mflop/s:  2925.26   Percentage:  6.82
Size: 129   Mflop/s:   2823.6   Percentage:  6.58
Size: 191   Mflop/s:  2893.04   Percentage:  6.74
Size: 192   Mflop/s:  2925.12   Percentage:  6.82
Size: 229   Mflop/s:  2834.69   Percentage:  6.61
Size: 255   Mflop/s:  2963.94   Percentage:  6.91
Size: 256   Mflop/s:  2712.55   Percentage:  6.32
Size: 257   Mflop/s:   2905.3   Percentage:  6.77
Size: 319   Mflop/s:  2878.31   Percentage:  6.71
Size: 320   Mflop/s:  2855.04   Percentage:  6.66
Size: 321   Mflop/s:  2835.52   Percentage:  6.61
Size: 417   Mflop/s:  2971.67   Percentage:  6.93
Size: 479   Mflop/s:  2876.16   Percentage:  6.70
Size: 480   Mflop/s:  2813.88   Percentage:  6.56
Size: 511   Mflop/s:  2717.75   Percentage:  6.34
Size: 512   Mflop/s:  1740.14   Percentage:  4.06
Size: 639   Mflop/s:  2614.61   Percentage:  6.09
Size: 640   Mflop/s:  2453.03   Percentage:  5.72
Size: 767   Mflop/s:  2494.76   Percentage:  5.82
Size: 768   Mflop/s:  2389.77   Percentage:  5.57
Size: 769   Mflop/s:   2779.2   Percentage:  6.48
Average percentage of Peak = 6.38822
```

Comment: Putting the `if` statements outside all of the loops would evaluate the expression only once rather than `M*N` times, but then you'd be left with even more of a mess.

Comment: Why would you make a local copy of an array without bothering to make it line up with the other array in the innermost loop so that the indexing is the same and you get sequential access?  Hoisting the indexing calculations to the top in a single variable may help, but using `restrict` (if applicable) might let the compiler do it for you.